# Grid layout alignment pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Trying to add some file upload button and merger app using Pyqt5.

Trying my first app in PyQt5. After creating a main window adding a grid layout with a button in it. when i run the code i get button centered in the widget.

My code is

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
import sys

class Main_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main_Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Parcel tally excel window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 450, 300)
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.main_widget = MainWidget(self)
        self.main_widget.selectbtn.clicked.connect(self.upload)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()
    def upload(self):
        print("function called")

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.mainLayout=QGridLayout()
        self.selectbtn = QPushButton(self)
        self.selectbtn.setText("Select file to upload")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.selectbtn)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

App=QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main_Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyjsI.jpg)

What I expect is the button must be coming on the top of the screen instead of center aligned.

I thought of ro stretch option I don't find any

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iEX6.jpg)

Comment: Laying out of widgets in a windowed program is not like a web page, by default they try to occupy all available space in the cell. Buttons have a fixed vertical size policy, so they are vertically centered in their cell grid. `self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.selectbtn, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)`. Also, you can only have one central widget, the QStackedWidget in your code is useless and will also be destroyed as soon as `setCentralWidget()` is called again.

Comment: @musicamante okay. I really dont get it how this heirarchy works, how the layout management is done?. Thanks for pointing out. Looks like i need to spend more time in docs

Comment: the layout of QStackedWidget is not required at all right?

Comment: You can start by reading the [layout documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), then I'd suggest to play around with [layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) too, so that you can better understand how they work. I don't understand your last question.